# How to select X.Org instead of Wayland from the command line?

Tags: xorg, 17.10, wayland

After some apt upgrades my Wayland session seems broken, the mouse moves but I can't click on anything. I want to try if X.Org works, but as the UI is broken, I must change the session type in the text console.

How do I configure X.Org to start instead of Wayland when the desktop UI is unusable, in the text console?

I got a workaround by using the keyboard: type <kbd>win</kbd>, `log out` and change focus with <kbd>TAB</kbd>. From there I could switch to X.Org using keyboard.

Comment: IIRC you set this up at =grub= level so when booting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In /etc/gdm3/custom.conf uncomment the line `WaylandEnable=false`.